# database table 2NF

Tags: database, normalization

I'm marking assignments and I may have complicated things more for myself.
I asked for tables to be 2NF at a minimum.  I understand the 2NF definition but for some reason I can't get through it with this example.  If they create a contributor table with the key being either SSN (or SIN for Canucks) and then add in the person's address information to the table, is it still 2NF?
Thanks.

EG:

PK int,
 PersonName nvarchar(200), 
StreetNumber int, 
StreetName    nvarchar(200),
 City nvarchar(200), 
ZIP nvarchar(10),  -- postalcode    in CDN

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As long as you only want to support a single address per person.

The candidate key is the integer "pk" and every column is related to it ans only it. If you were to have two rows (for two addresses) and had to copy the person name twice, then it would not be 2NF.